# MongoDB $aggregate $push multiple fields in Java Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongo

I have a mongo aggregate group query:

```
db.wizard.aggregate(
{
$group: {
    _id: "$title",
    versions: { $push: {version:"$version", author:"$author", dateAdded:"$dateAdded"}}
    }
})
```

I need this query in Java Spring-Data-MongoDB, my current solution looks like this:

```
    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.group("title").
                    push("version").as("versions")
    );
```

Problem is that i don't know how to add more fields to push method (version, author, dateAdded).
Is it possible with Spring-Data-MongoDB?

Comment: If you want to put "stringified" mongo-shell query, extend `AggregationOperation` class and override `toDBObject` or similar method (depending on drive version). I used to workaround lot of aggregate steps which is not compatible with native Spring Data

Comment: If need, I can add an example how to do that

Comment: it would be great if you post an example

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can directly pass the BasicDbObject to any of the aggregation pipeline stage.

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
            group("title").
            push(new BasicDBObject
                   ("version", "$version").append
                   ("author", "$author").append
                   ("dateAdded", "$dateAdded")).as("versions"));
```

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** MongoDB versión 2.6 - 3.0 (compatible Java driver)

I've extended `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation` class to implement custom `toDBObject` method:

```
public class GenericAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {

    private String operator;
    private DBObject query;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * 
     * @param operator MongoDB operator ($group, $sort, $project, etc..)
     * @param query MongoDB aggregation query step string
     */
    public GenericAggregationOperation(String operator, String query) {
        this(operator, (DBObject) JSON.parse(query));
    }

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     * 
     * @param operator MongoDB operator ($group, $sort, $project, etc..)
     * @param query MongoDB aggregation query step DBObject
     */
    public GenericAggregationOperation(String operator, DBObject query) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.query    = query;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {

        return new BasicDBObject(operator, query);
    }

}
```

In your case, it would be:

```
List<AggregationOperation> list = new ArrayList<AggregationOperation>();
lista.add(new GenericAggregationOperation("$group", "{ \"_id\": \"$title\", \"versions\": { \"$push\": { \"version\":\"$version\", \"author\":\"$author\", \"dateAdded\":\"$dateAdded\"}} }"));

TypedAggregation<EpisodeIndexDto> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    YourClassTitleVersion.class, list);
mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, YourClassTitleVersion.class,
    YourClassTitleVersion.class).getMappedResults();
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

In the new version spring-data-mongodb:2.x.x the AggregationOperation need to return Document instead of DBObject, so the updated class will be:

```
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationContext;

public class GenericAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {

    private String operator;
    private DBObject query;

    public GenericAggregationOperation(String operator, DBObject query) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.query = query;
    }

    public GenericAggregationOperation(String operator, String query) {
        this(operator, BasicDBObject.parse(query));
    }

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document(operator, query);
    }
}
```

Plus to make it easier to be used I'll add utility interface (java 8+, for java 7 or lower you can convert this to class utils instead):

```
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation;

public interface GenericAggregationUtils {

    static AggregationOperation aggregate(String operation, String query) {
        return new GenericAggregationOperation(operation, query);
    }

    static AggregationOperation aggregate(String operation, DBObject query) {
        return new GenericAggregationOperation(operation, query);
    }

}
```

And then we can static import the interface into our class:

```
import static com.example.mongodb.aggregation.GenericAggregationUtils.*;
```

And use it in the aggregation pipeline together with other spring data AggregationOperation like this:

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(YourDocCollection.class,
    aggregate("$group", "{ \"_id\": \"$title\", \"versions\": { \"$push\": { \"version\":\"$version\", \"author\":\"$author\", \"dateAdded\":\"$dateAdded\"}} }"),
    sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "title"),
    ...
);
```