# Mongodb spring data group _id toLower or case insensitive

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have mongodb facet and aggregate query in spring boot using mongo template and aggregation query. everything works fine except case sensitivity of value. I have below query in mongodb:

```
db.getCollection('product').aggregate([{"colors":[{$unwind:"$variants"},
{"$group": {
        _id: { $toLower: "$variants.color" },
        count:{$sum:1},
        image : { $first: '$variants.color_image' },
    }}

]
```

I have equivalent spring data query:

```
Aggregation.facet(unwind("variants"), group("variants.color").count().as("count").first("variants.color_image").as("image"))
            .as("colors");
```

But here how can I mention toLower to group field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring-boot does not allow complex aggregations as you can do in shell. So, you may apply such *workaround*.

Let's change your facet query by this (create new field where we set lower case color value):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "colors": [
        {
          $unwind: "$variants"
        },
        {
          $addFields: {
            "variants.color_lower": {
              $toLower: "$variants.color"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$group": {
            _id: "$variants.color_lower",
            count: {
              $sum: 1
            },
            image: {
              $first: "$variants.color_image"
            },

          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1Ednb3G58t4)

Now, Spring-Boot allows to define custom [AggregationOperation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/AggregationOperation.html#toPipelineStages-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationContext-) (Generic solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39405880/3710490)):

```
public class LowerAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation() {

    @Override
    public List<Document> toPipelineStages(AggregationOperationContext context) {

        return Arrays.asList(
            new Document("$addFields", 
                new Document("variants.color_lower", 
                    new Document("$toLower", "$variants.color")))
        );
    }

}
```

Now, you complete your facet aggregation:

```
Aggregation.facet(
    unwind("variants"), 
    new LowerAggregationOperation(),
    group("variants.color_lower").count().as("count").first("variants.color_image").as("image"))
.as("colors");
```

Comment: Is that possible to input all aggregation stages in to one method and get the output? Eg: `unwind`, `lookup`, `group` query as String and get the output

Comment: @varman What do you mean? You need to build valid aggregation pipeline. If you can do so in MongoDB shell, you can try doing within Spring-data

Comment: Of course, what I do is, after checking the mongo script in shell, i do in spring like `Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(match(..),lookup(..),unwind(..),group(..))`. Instead of rewriting again in Spring, can't we have a method that gets the already written mongo script as a String parameter which returns the output same as shell?

Comment: @varman Ah, I see. Ofcourse, you need to call MongoDB aggregate method with list of Document. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643109/mongodb-aggregation-with-java-driver). Take a look `Document.parse`