# How to use like $dateToString in Aggregation $group for Spring Data Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I need to implement aggregation in Spring-Data MongoDB.

This aggregation `$group` works successfully in Mongo Compass:

```
$group{
  {
    _id:  { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" }},
    doc: {"$push":"$$ROOT"}

  }
}
```

This is the result expected group by year month and day and push results with all field in array docs
[image: Conmpass]

I try to implement this aggregation Spring Mongo:

[image: My implementation]

My problem is that lose data and only get a date by the previous projection.

I prefer not use the `$project` and only `$group` stage.

[image: My actual result]

Comment: Spring Data MongoDB doesn't support group operation on AggregationExpression. So you have to use projection pipeline before the group stage.

Comment: You may implement custom AggregationOperation explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39405880/3710490) and use same `$group` pipeline stage instead of `$project`

Comment: thanks for reply works $project

Comment: But your choice is exactly what I wanted to do.
I wanted to be able to use pure mongo queries because I have complex queries
thanks valijon