# Map a field in aggregation using Spring Mongo (java)

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to get one property from one array that has a bunch of properties in my document and put the result as a new array

This is a simple aggregation with map. I can do that with mongo in the shell by using the following query:

```
db.getCollection('foo').aggregate([ 
  { '$project': { 'newField': { '$map': { input: '$contacts', in: '$$this.email' } } }
])
```

I cannot create this in Java with Spring Mongo, though. I checked the documentation and I found this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation.supported-aggregation-operations

I could create this with that info and the help of my IDE:

```
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project()
   .and(VariableOperators.Map.itemsOf("contacts")
   .as("c")
   .andApply(document -> new Document("newFieldArray", StringOperators.valueOf("c.email")))).as("newField")
```

but it returns null and on top of that it's very hard to debug. I keep seeing this in the debugger:

> "includedDivisions" : { "$map" : { "input" : "$contacts",
>   "as" : "c", "in" : { "c" : { "$java" :
>   org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.StringOperators$StringOperatorFactory@796460bf
>   } } } },

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Spring-data doesn't offer full support for Query DSL.

So, you need to extend `AggregationOperation` explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39405880/3710490) and setup your raw query as BasicDBObject / Document (depending on your MongoDB version).

```
AggregationOperation project =
    new GenericAggregationOperation(
       "$project", 
       "{ \"newField\": { \"$map\": { \"input\": \"$contacts\", \"in\": \"$$this.email\" } } }"
);
Operations.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(project), ...);
```